# A socket with c server over java socket

Tags: java, c, sockets

My assignment requiers me to write an server in c but client in java. I need to send some integer to my client as instructions. They can connected smoothly but my java client cannot Receive the integer send from c server. there is only two possibilities: my c server did not send the Number out OR my client does not Receive the integer correctly. The c server is able to loop as I type in since the printf and scanf is executed while nothing happends on the client side.

I am stuck here, any help will be appreciate!

=========================================================================
UPDATE:
I correct the main class in java where the class name of the client into dotClient, and my client was able to conncected and read the inputs from the server. 
I have try to send an 'int' directly in the server side, but When the client(java) use DataInputStream.ReadInt(), it returns a randomly big number as if the size of int in c and size of int in java is not matched.When I use a c client to do the same job, it works normal. So there is Hidden Problem for using dataInputStream directly with a c server, as I tried readShort() and ReadLong() as well.

As suggested, I use bufferReader. 
And send string in server side, and perse it into int in client.
it works.

hère is my updated c code

```
#define PORT 55555 

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) 

{ 
int server_fd, new_socket, valread; 
struct sockaddr_in address; 
int opt = 1; 
int addrlen = sizeof(address); 

char buffer[1024]; 
int returnSend = 0;

// Creating socket file descriptor 
if (
    (server_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))
     == 0) 
{ 
    perror("socket failed"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
} 
printf("%s\n", "Socket created!");

// Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
if (setsockopt(server_fd, SOL_SOCKET,
    SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt))) 
{ 
    perror("setsockopt"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
} 
printf("Socket attached!\n");

address.sin_family = AF_INET; 
address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
address.sin_port = htons( PORT ); 

// Forcefully attaching socket to the port 8080 
if (bind(server_fd, 
    (struct sockaddr *)&address,  
     sizeof(address))<0) 
{ 
    perror("bind failed"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
} 
printf("socket binded!\n");

if (listen(server_fd, 3) < 0) 
{ 
    perror("listen"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
} 
printf("socket listened!\n");

if ((new_socket = accept(server_fd,
    (struct sockaddr *)&address,  
    (socklen_t*)&addrlen))<0) 
{ 
    perror("accept"); 
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
}// Socket formulated !

do{
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin); 
    returnSend = write(new_socket , buffer , strlen(buffer));
    printf("Sending: %sReturn returnSend: %d.\n", buffer,returnSend); 

} while (1);
return 0; 

}
```

hère is my updated java client

```
import java.net.*; 
import java.io.*; 

public class dotClient 
{ 
    // initialize socket and input output streams

        private Socket echoSocket= null;
        private BufferedReader input = null;

// constructor to put ip address and port 
    public dotClient(String address, int port) 
    { 
    // establish a connection 
    try
    { 
            echoSocket = new Socket(address, port); 
            System.out.println("Connected");

         input =
        new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(echoSocket.getInputStream()));

    } 
    catch(UnknownHostException u) 
    { 
        System.out.println("exception 1: "+u); 
    } 
    catch(IOException i) 
    { 
        System.out.println("exception 2: "+i); 
    } 

    int number = 0;
    String line = "";
    // keep reading until read neagaive integer

    try
    {   
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) 
        {
        number = Integer.parseInt(line);
        System.out.println("String is :"+line);
        System.out.println("number is :"+number);

        } 
    }
    catch(IOException i)
    { 
        System.out.println("Exception 3: "+i); 
    } 

    // close the connection 
    try
    { 
        input.close(); 
        out.close(); 
        echoSocket.close(); 
        System.out.println("Connection closed!");
    } 
    catch(IOException i) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Exception 4: "+i); 
    } 
} 

public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
    dotClient client = new dotClient("192.168.0.3", 55555); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Does the server work if you telnet into it? That way you can see the commands and check if the java client can deal with it.

Comment: Since this is a text protocol, you might want to use a BufferedDataReader and a PrintWriter for input and output.

Comment: @NomadMaker do you mean BufferedReader?

Comment: You need to add error checking to your code so you understand what it's doing. For example, what is the return value from `send`? Is it what you expect? Your code doesn't check. So how can you troubleshoot?

Comment: @徐良亮 Yes, BufferedReader. My bad.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Thanks for the advise! yes, I thought about that and add a if statement to check if the send works. It turns out works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `main` method you are creating a `Client` instance but your class is called `dotClient`. You might want to ensure you are creating an instance of your class `dotClient`. Otherwise I agree with the previous comments and would suggest BufferedReader and BufferedWriter/PrintWriter for the IO.

Do any of your try blocks catch an exception on the client? Check the return value of `send(new_socket , &number , size(number) , 0 );` on the server to make sure the data was actually sent for more info checkout http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/send.2.html.